# How to Fire a function in the Firefox addon when button is clicked from the Website

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

How do call a function in the Firefox addon when button in my website is clicked....

As well how to get data from HTML FORM to Firefox addon using javascript

Answer (score 0):

You have to addeventlistner to the html window, you have to access the browser and tab

From your addon, access the browser like this:

```
const {interfaces: Ci, utils: Cu, classes: Cc} = Components;
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');

var recentChromeWindow = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');

var tab1 = recentChromeWindow.gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[0];
var browser1 = tab1.linkedBrowser;
var htmlWindow1 = browser1.contetnWindow;
```

now say in your addon you have a function called `doit`

and theres an element in tab1 with id `rawr` you would do this:

`htmlWindow1.document.getElementById('rawr').addEventListener('click', rawr, false);`

See this doc page for lots of good info on this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser